# Show Modal dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taskbar

How can I create a modal dialog in winform without creating a new taskbar item?

I'm instanciating my modal as:

```
FrmDialog dialog = new FrmDialog();
dialog .ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand since ShowDialog opens your window as a modal window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the showInTaskbar property:

```
dialog.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the [`ShowInTaskBar` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) to `false`.

```
var dialog = new FrmDialog();
dialog.ShowInTaskbar = false;
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

[MSDN ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx)